# Can not apply video setting dictionary to AVCaptureMovieFileOutput

Tags: python, macos, video, avfoundation, pyobjc

I wrote a small script to record video from a webcam, via PyObjC. I needed to apply a dictionary named `video_settings` which I specified in `startRecordingToOutputFileURL_recordingDelegate_` function. with the settings of the video being recorded. But after the video recording test, the setting did not apply. How make that, to set settings dictionary for video, during recoding?
Bellow, script:

```
import time

import pathlib

from AVFoundation import *

from AppKit import *


def record(length: int, name: str):
    session = AVCaptureSession.alloc().init()

    device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType_(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    input_ = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice_error_(device, None)[0]
    session.addInput_(input_)
    output_url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(name)

    video_settings = {
        AVVideoWidthKey: 640,
        AVVideoHeightKey: 180,
        AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: {
            AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: 10000000,
            AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264HighAutoLevel,
            AVVideoAllowFrameReorderingKey: kCFBooleanFalse
        },
        AVVideoColorPropertiesKey: {
            AVVideoColorPrimariesKey: AVVideoColorPrimaries_ITU_R_709_2,
            AVVideoTransferFunctionKey: AVVideoTransferFunction_ITU_R_709_2,
            AVVideoFieldMode: kCFBooleanTrue

        }
    }

    output = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput.alloc().init()
    session.addOutput_(output)
    session.startRunning()

    output.startRecordingToOutputFileURL_recordingDelegate_(output_url, CFDictionaryRef(video_settings))

    time.sleep(length)

    output.stopRecording()
    session.stopRunning()
    return session


record(3, 'video_file.mov')

path = pathlib.Path('video_file.mov').cwd().__str__() + '/video_file.mov'
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openFile_(path)
```